# Overriding name property of named functions

Tags: javascript

I have a named function like below:

```
var foo = function ninjaFunc(){

};
```

checking its name in console, I found "ninjaFunc" which is expected:

```
console.log(foo.name); //-> "ninjaFunc"
```

I just reassigned `foo.name` to `'aha'`. It runs without any error.

```
foo.name = 'aha'; //compiles without error
```

but reexamining `foo.name`, I found "ninjaFunc" again. But I expected it to be "aha" as the compiler didn't raise error while assigining it.

```
console.log(foo.name); //-> "ninjaFunc"
```

Why so ? which concept I am missing ?

Comment: [MDN: function.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) `[...]You cannot change the name of a function, this property is read-only[...]`  (`This is an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) proposal.`)

Comment: But why it didn't catch exception while I was trying to change ? like foo.name = 'aha' in my example.

Comment: Because setting a not writable property is not required to throw an error: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s8sceLnp/)

Comment: may be not required.

Comment: The non strict mode will not throw an error, when switching to strict mode, writing to a readonly property will throw an error.

Comment: Why do you want to change the name?

Answer (score -1):

The normative reference for ECMAScript is ECMA-262, i.e. the language specification. The current standard, ES5, doesn't specify a *name* property for [*function instances*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5).

However, the draft of edition 6 does in [*§19.2.4.2*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-name):

> This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }.

Which says you can't write to it (writeable:false) per [*§6.1.7.1*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-property-attributes).

Implementations may have implemented the ed. 6 behaviour, or not. You will need to test various browsers to determine support (e.g. it is not supported in IE 6 and possibly later versions).

Comment: Hey you just quoted it from the prototype property. I checked the section of name where it is mentioned that this property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }.

Comment: `[...]can write to it (writeable:true), but you can't modify it (configurable: false) as defined in §6.1.7.1. So writing to it doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't do anything.[...]`  is wrong. `configurable: false` will protect the property descriptor and the property form being deleted, but will not have an effect on if it is writeable.  Only setting `writable: false` (or using a setter)  can protect the property from being overwritten. If the script runs in _strict mode_  deleting a `configurable: false` property throws an error and writing to `writable: false` throws an error.

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud—yes, you're right, I quoted from the wrong part, fixed.

Comment: @t.niese—yes, I quoted from the wrong part of the specification. :-( Fixed.